# SVG background blur with polygon

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to blur background with polygon svg shape. Below is svg. And here is [Bin](http://jsbin.com/seziviwuta/edit?html,css,output)

```
<svg id="testSVG" style="position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;height: 100%;width: 100%;opacity: 0.5;">
  <defs>
   <filter id="blurry" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" in="SourceGraphic" result="blurSquares"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feComponentTransfer in="blurSquares" result="opaqueBlur">
        <feFuncA type="linear" intercept="1"></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="opaqueBlur" in2="SourceGraphic"></feBlend>
   </filter>
  </defs>
  <g filter="url(#blurry)">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,200 0,200 0,0"></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I am expecting to see part of background image blurred. But it is not working as expected. What changes are required to make it work?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to blur the area of a background image that is covered by the polygon?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yes exactly!

Answer (score 4):

There is no reliable way for a blur filter in an SVG to automatically blur something behind the SVG on the page.

To achieve what you want, the background image has to be copied into the SVG and the blur filter applied to that.  Of course you would need to make sure that the image in the HTML and the version of it in the SVG line up correctly.

So, for example, here's a version of your example with a blurred image in the SVG. But no polygon yet.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  background-image: url('http://wp.patheos.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/faithwalkers/files/2013/03/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg');
}
```

```html
<svg id="testSVG" style="position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;height: 100%;width: 100%;">
   <defs>
      <filter id="blurry">
         <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" in="SourceGraphic"></feGaussianBlur>
      </filter>
   </defs>

   <image x="0" y="0"
          width="500" height="332"
          xlink:href="http://wp.patheos.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/faithwalkers/files/2013/03/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg"
          filter="url(#blurry)" />
</svg>
```

Now if we want the blurred image to be inside the polygon, we can do that with a clipping path.

We turn the polygon into a clipping path and apply that to the blurred image.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  background-image: url('http://wp.patheos.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/faithwalkers/files/2013/03/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg');
}
```

```html
<svg id="testSVG" style="position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;height: 100%;width: 100%;">
   <defs>
      <filter id="blurry">
         <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" in="SourceGraphic"></feGaussianBlur>
      </filter>

      <clipPath id="polyclip">
          <polygon points="50,200, 300,50, 400,300" />
      </clipPath>
  </defs>

   <image x="0" y="0"
          width="500" height="332"
          xlink:href="http://wp.patheos.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/faithwalkers/files/2013/03/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg"
          filter="url(#blurry)"
          clip-path="url(#polyclip)" />
</svg>
```

Note that I'm using a slightly more interesting triangle polygon here. So that the effect is more obvious.

Comment: You can use a BackgroundImage pseudo input to access the background on browsers that support it. IE has support, not sure what other browsers do (Firefox doesn't support this).

Comment: Yeah, I probably shouldn't have said "no way". But it is effectively true since `in="BackgroundImage"` is not well supported.

Comment: Only IE support BackgroundImage but Safari now has a (non-standard) backdrop filter as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put This code in your Polygon Tag :

```
<polygon points="200,0 0,160 500,330" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1"></polygon>
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  background-image: url('http://wp.patheos.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/faithwalkers/files/2013/03/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg');
}
```

```html
<svg id="testSVG" style="position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;height: 100%;width: 100%;opacity: 0.5;">
  <defs>
   <filter id="blurry" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" in="SourceGraphic" result="blurSquares"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feComponentTransfer in="blurSquares" result="opaqueBlur">
        <feFuncA type="linear" intercept="1"></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="opaqueBlur" in2="SourceGraphic"></feBlend>
   </filter>
  </defs>
  <g filter="url(#blurry)">
    <polygon points="200,0 0,160, 500,330" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1"></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if you remove your feComponentTransfer and feBlend tags.

http://jsbin.com/tuyorotome/1/edit?html,css,output